# Permission denied when I try to read an image in my package folder from my widget (android)

Tags: android, widget

I have an application with a built-in widget and I'm trying to read an image from my package folder (/data/data/com.package.name/pic.jpg) via my widget, but when I try to read it I get "Permission denied" in logcat. file.canRead() returns true so I'm not really sure what's wrong here. Isn't it allowed to read from the package folder via a widget?
Do I have to create the image on the sdcard to be able to read it or is there another way? I would prefer to read it from my package folder but it doesn't seem to work.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What's the full error message in logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that by "widget" you really mean "app widget". If my assumption is incorrect, please ignore this answer. :-)

The home screen needs to be able to read the image. The home screen runs in its own process and does not have rights to any of your files.

> Isn't it allowed to read from the package folder via a widget?

The home screen is not allowed to read from your app's files. So, if you are using `setImageViewUri()` with a `file://` `Uri`, that would be your problem.

> Do I have to create the image on the sdcard to be able to read it or is there another way?

External storage would be one solution. Another would be to create the file using `openFileOutput()` using `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`. Yet another would be to create a tiny `ContentProvider` and use a `content://` `Uri`.

Comment: creating the file with openFileOutput() solved my problem! Thanks a lot for the help!